# Does query_posts have an effect on get_the_category?

Tags: wordpress

I am having trouble debugging a situation, and I think some better background information on how these systems work would be very helpful.  I know that the use of the function `query_posts()` is strongly discouraged.  But let's just assume that there is nothing I can do to remove it from the code.  Specifically the query is changed to pull posts of a post_type (a post_type specific to the theme I am using).  This is what the query looks like after it has been changed:

> posts_per_page=10&paged=0&post_type=project

Then the loop begins and it can successfully grab the titles for each post.  But when I call `get_the_category()` it returns an empty array, even though all of the posts have categories.  I verified that it was an empty array with `var_dump`.

I am do not have a super strong understanding of how these systems work, so the emphasis on not using query_posts has me worried.  Is there any possible interaction between query_posts and `get_the_category()` that could cause it to not work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)? Im not sure it is cause by `query_posts`, but [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) alters  Wordpress Main Loop (global `$wp_query`).

You can use the `WP_Query` method like this, by replacing with your `query_posts` loop

```
$newLoop = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=10&paged=0&post_type=project');

if ( $newLoop->has_posts() ) {
    while ( $newLoop->has_posts() ) { $newLoop->the_post();
        the_title(); // Your title
        var_dump ( get_the_category() ); // this should not be empty if category assigned to current post
    }
}
```

If you still want to go with `query_posts` try one of the methods below:

Try passing post id manually:

```
get_the_category( get_the_ID() ); // Must be in loop
```

Or try adding this:

```
// after endwhile of query_posts
wp_reset_query();
```